# There used to be many, even more than (there) are today

Tags: ellipsis, subjects, dummy-pronouns

> There used to be many, even more than (**there**) are today.
>
> There were many, even more than (**there**) are today.

Is **there** optional is both sentences?

Answer (score 2):

This [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) provides a good summary of the main types of ellipsis.
As you can see, it does not include any type of ellipsis that would permit the omission of just the introducing adverb **there**.

You can, however, omit **there are** from both sentences.

> There used to be many, even more than today.
> There were many, even more than today.

We could explain this in two ways. First, they could be examples of ellipsis- comparative deletion of **there are**. For comparative deletion, we don't have to have an exact match between the verbs in the two clauses, so **there are** can match both **there were** and also **there used to be**.

There is also a non-ellipsis explanation.  **[than](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/than)** can function as a conjunction or as a preposition. In the original sentences, **than** was a conjunction followed by the clause **there are today**. In the shorter versions, **than** is a preposition, with **today** acting as a noun.